# Apple Watch message: "Sign Into Complete Purchase"

Tags: apple-watch

My Apple Watch 4 keeps showing this message asking for an Apple Id authentication that is my email but not my apple id really.

> #### Sign Into Complete Purchase
>
> Enter the password for you Apple ID "email@example.com".

I did a lot of research already of what it could be trying to do and no luck.

[image: "Sign Into Complete Purchase" on Apple Watch]

Comment: Have you installed a custom watch face from the AppStore? Or some other AppleWatch app?

Comment: I would be very careful about that... the mistake in the heading "Into" instead of "In To" - and the fact that it is asking for an Apple-ID password on the watch - all makes me think this is some kind of phishing attac and not legitimate at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the fix!

1. Open your Apple Watch app on your phone and go to “**My Watch**”
2. Go to **Settings/General** & turn off **Automatic App Install**.
3. Now go back to “**My Watch**” and scroll to the bottom to see “Available Apps”.
4. Any apps you see that are trying to install are the culprits causing the notifications!
5. Delete those apps from your phone, and if necessary reinstall them with your Apple ID used currently.
6. Turn Automatic App Install back on if necessary.

You now won't receive any more of those annoying notifications!

Comment: That's great. Really helped to at least stop the messages.

Comment: What I still could not figure out is why its using my corporate email as apple id when trying to install these apps. Even checked the apple id on the watch settings and it shows the correct one (not the corporate one its asking for the password).

Answer (score 0):

This can occur if an app needs to update and it was previously used on another apple Id or associated. Sometimes it the update all together. You can either do what the previous poster put OR unpair and repair watch and set up a new. Then sign into the watch.